# AJAX XMLHttpRequest Error Flag

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest

I made a query to an address and I got the `readyState = 4`, and the `status = 0`.

After I read the documentation for the `XMLHttpRequest`, it says if the `status = 0` and `readyState = 4`, then check the [associated error flag](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#error-flag).

How can I see what's in this error flag to determine the cause of the status not being set to `200`?

Answer (score 0):

I've heard that the XHR editor said that the error flag referenced in the spec is an internal implementation variable that consumers cannot access.

In other words, you can't see that "error flag".